# Why does JavaScript have both `.prototype` and internal `.[[prototype]]`?

Tags: javascript, prototype, language-design, prototypal-inheritance

This is about language design of JavaScript: why does JavaScript have both `.prototype` and internal `.[[prototype]]`?

**Why it doesn't always use read-write property `.prototype` instead of having hidden read-only property `.[[prototype]]` which is used to search for inherited properties?**

This would have allowed JavaScript to work without keyword `new` and any magic hidden properties. In addition, the prototype inheritance chain of any object could have been modified during runtime and the call binding would still work according to the current value pointed by `.prototype` (instead of read-only `.[[prototype]]` which cannot be modified after creating an object like today).

If `.prototype` were used for searching properties instead, one could do stuff like

```
let o = { name: "Jack", age: 42 };
o.prototype = Person;
o.greet();
```

and JavaScript engine would follow `.prototype` chain (instead of `.[[prototype]]` like today) to object `Person` to find the function `greet()`, which would be called with `this` set to the object referenced by `o`. Similarly `o.toString()` would follow the `.prototype` chain up to `Object` and use default implementation if not implemented by some object earlier in the chain.

I guess there's some good reason to have separate values for `.prototype` and `.[[prototype]]` but I cannot figure it out. What I'm missing? The only thing I can think of is that allowing read-write access to inheritance chain would allow creating loops, but such loop would been easy to detect during the property search and engine could just throw an exception along the lines `TypeError: detected loop in .prototype chain while searching property XYZ`. (There's also `setPrototypeOf()` which shows that JavaScript could technically support this.)

Comment: You're mostly describing [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). Although it's deprecated. At any rate, I'm not really sure what you're asking here. I can say that having public properties is a problem when you consider JSON like `'{ "partType": "engine", "prototype": true }'`

Comment: I'm basically asking *why* there was `.__proto__` separate from `.prototype` in the first place? I understand that *current* implementation of JSON.parse() would be problematic if it allowed defining the prototype chain but if the language design had been different, JSON.parse() design would obviously match it.

Comment: (Note that `__proto__` is literally alternative spelling for `.[[prototype]]` in that they represent the same thing but neither is specified as real property in ECMAScript standard.)

Comment: See also: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects-deconstruction